# tsc command output empty js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am learning Angular/Typescript and found my first issue. Don't even know how to ask it correctly. Searched it around and got nothing.

I have a **main.ts** file with this code

```
function myFunc(x,y){
    return x+y;
}

let num = 2;
const PI = 3.14;
```

When I do the command

> `tsc main.ts`

It creates an empty file named **main.js**

In the video course I am watching, the generated file is populated with the corresponding javascript.

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you open the terminal in the same folder as your .ts file?

Comment: I am using VS Code. I opened the terminal from it.

Comment: Using VS Code terminal does not necessary mean that your main.ts is in the same directory that your current directory of the terminal. Ensure that both are in the same directory

Comment: Did @Kokodoko's suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie. I'm using command prompt. What are the files that should be in the same directory? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue. I quickly realized that I haven't save the main.ts file on VS code by running:

`cat main.ts`

In that case, you are basically compiling an empty file. I guess the tutorial did not bother to mention that you should manually save your file.

Comment: If you are use-to PhpStorm and auto-save, VS code have same option.
File -> Autosave

Answer (score 6):

You first need to save the file. `(Ctrl + s)`.
Otherwise compiler will compile an empty file.

So you should manually save the file.

Answer (score 1):

Type in your IDE's terminal 'npm install -g eslint'
save all, and reload project. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your main.ts file under "Open Editor" before running the node main.js in VS Code terminal.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this after checking my **package.json** and seeing that I had forgotten to `--save` my various `npm install`s.

I would advise you to always double-check you package and tsconfig files.